# For previously asked questions in a quickly changing technology, how can I properly ask, "Is this still the best answer?"

Tags: discussion

I have a question regarding JavaScript. The question exists at least three times on Stack Overflow. Each of those questions is now several years old (and each has a different accepted answer), and JavaScript is a relatively quickly changing language. Is there any way I can ask, "Hey, are these still the best solutions to my issue, or have there been recent developments?" If so, what's the proper approach?

FYI, in this case, the three existing Stack Overflow questions can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54116070/how-can-i-unit-test-non-exported-functions), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31922977/testing-typescript-function-which-is-not-exported), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14874208/how-to-access-and-test-an-internal-non-exports-function-in-a-node-js-module). But this is not the first time I've wondered if the answers I see on Stack Overflow are still the best answers.

Comment: You would have to definitely define your criteria for “best” since “best” is definitely subjective and an extremely broad description. You would have to be explicit about what your question was exactly, “is this the best”, would instantly get a close vote from this user.

Comment: 1. The second and third link are for literally the same question. 2. The (total of) two questions you show are different - one is for JS + Jest the other with TS + Mocha + Chai. 3. *Both* of these say the same thing - you cannot test unexported functions. So, the only way to do test them is to *export them*. Then both show workarounds that are broadly similar anyway. I'm not sure where you get "different answer" when the workaround is always "export the functions but group them to know that you shouldn't import them in non-test code"

Comment: "JavaScript is a relatively quickly changing language". It's really not though (changes come once a year), and the changes are almost always additive, so the "old way" of doing things still work fine. Also, what @VLAZ said :).

Comment: Regarding the meta question at hand and not the particular case, If you have a strong feeling that the solutions there aren't up to date, then a bounty sounds like the way to go. If you can't apply any of the answers there because you are in a very particular case, then open a new question explaining exactly why your case is so particular. But I've got the feeling this meta question was already asked...

Comment: @VLAZ I've fixed the third link, thanks. And you're correct that two of them provide workarounds--one suggests carrying out a conditional export (based on env vars) and the other suggests a third party package.  What I'm specifically wondering is, has Node perhaps added one or more features which make it easier to to conditionally export a function, or remove the need for the third party package?  But again, in this particular question I'm not asking for help on my JavaScript issue. I'm asking if one can ever ask, "Are these answers still up to date?"

Comment: Most users will update the answer accordingly if you leave a comment.

Comment: @HereticMonkey we could say it took some time to get up to speed with changes since 1995 ..

Answer (score 0):

"Best" is a moving target.  I could almost promise that the solutions proposed weren't exactly the *best* at the time, either, but they were what worked.

If you want to know if this is still relevant or applicable, ask *that* instead.  Don't use "best" since this implies that there is truly one way to accomplish this.

Comment: "Best" or "still relevant" seems to be much of a muchness... Something that doesn't work,  by default does not qualify... and there are only two possible meanings for best: most understandable and maintainable, or fastest. While the former could be a matter of opinion, the latter can only vary by platform. So not as dynamic as you say. There might usually be many ways to do things, but in my experience there usually IS only one BEST way... even if it may vary from person to person. Still, each person will share what they deem best.

Comment: @dagelf there are many more variations than what you suggest. You actually said "two" and listed three, for a start. Even then "fastest" doesn't vary that much by platform. You could have difference in runtime due to your input, for example. You could optimise for only certain inputs. There is a whole other side to this - whether the increased speed *matters* - you might be able to reduce the runtime but give up something in return. And if you reduce the speed by 1ms for something that runs once, it's not as good as shaving 0.1ms off of something that runs a million times.

Answer (score -2):

Thank you for your question!

It seems that this situation currently sorts itself out within the community.

When asking a new question, you have full authority to explain yourself and clarify why similar questions do not best represent your current need. From here, the community can choose to agree or disagree with your conclusion and answer your question or not. Knowledge will be gained and shared as the community sees fit.

The community can freely choose to accept this answer or not. They should feel free to do exactly as they see fit. The whole point of this platform is to ask great, well-reasearched questions which turn into solutions that appear as the top results in major search engines.

From a personal perspective, asking a question causes you to ask yourself whether or not the question may have already been addressed on the platform. "Maybe I haven't done enough research..." or, "I have exhausted all of my sources, and here is what I have found out so far:... Does someone have anything else to add? What am I missing"

Let the community decide, and allow yourself to grow with it!

Comment: FYI Downvotes means "thanks" on StackOverflow.... ask me, I've probably got the most. (People here don't like it if you say thanks)

Comment: I'm really trying to see how this answer is specific to the OP, and not just some generalized statement of participation.